# Why would the actual value form LocalStorage.getItem be undefined after being saved?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I tried to get a value to keep incrementing after reloading by saving it in localStorage but when I do localStorage.getItem it gives me undefined

```
// function to reload matched and store val score
 const winnigs = function() {     
              alert('Player X WON!');
              val = false;
              playx.innerHTML++;
              localStorage.setItem('score', JSON.stringify(playx.innerHTML));

              maindi[0].appendChild(paro);
 // function to reload             
              setTimeout(reload, 2000);
              

}
```

```
// it keeps on going back to 0 after refresh 
(() => { 
let score = localStorage.getItem('score').numeric;
if(score === undefined ){
   playx.innerHTML = 0;
}else {
   playx.innerHTML = score;
}
})()
```

after reload in Local storage shows Key: score, Value: "1", **.numeric** handles **NaN** which is great but why would it still be undefined?

Comment: `"1".numeric` is `undefined`. Do you want to do something like `parseInt(localStorage.getItem('score'))`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```js
localStorage.getItem('score');
```

instead of

```
localStorage.getItem('score').numeric;
```

Because `.numeric` is not the property of `localStorage.getItem()`, so it will return `undefined`